# Android studio - informing a class when something happens in another class (custom broadcast receiver)

Tags: android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I need a Class to inform the MainActivity when something happens. How best to achieve this?

My app is a space game. One Class manages collision checking and establishes when a collision with a fuel cell occurs. How can the MainActivity be notified of this in order to increase the score on the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Having investigated several possible solutions to this problem, the best one by far was to set up a **custom broadcast receiver**. The class that realises there has been a collision sends a broadcast. This is then picked up by the MainActivity, which can then update the UI. Custom broadcast receivers are flexible and very useful - but their implementation can be quite difficult to understand, even reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). So I've created a step-by-step guide to set up a Android Studio custom broadcast receiver. It works best when you need to communicate between different parts of the same app, although can be adapated to the more conventional uses of broadcast receiver such as android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED or android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

**Easy 2 Step Guide to Setting Up Custom Broadcast Receiver**

**Step 1 - In the class when the Broadcast needs to be sent:**
a)  create new **Intent**
b)  **setAction** with the name of the broadcast - this will be the same in the receiving Activity (step 2) and in the Manifest (step 3) 
c)  and add any **Extras** – you can retrieve these when the broadcast is received

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.daplipcoding.broadcast.blockWonBroadcast");
intent.putExtra("wonBlock", 0); //0=block won
```

d)  send the broadcast – note that you will need the applicationContext.  You may need to pass the applicationContext via the constructor into this class, and then use this context to send the broadcast

```
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Step 2 - In the Activity that needs to be notified:**
a)  set a private BroadcastReceiver parameter

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
```

b)  create new **IntentFilter**. 
c)  **addAction** to the IntentFilter for the broadcast you are interested in 
d)  create new **BroadcastReceiver** – this will override the **OnReceive** method – this is where you put your logic to respond to the broadcast
e)  all important! **register** the receiver

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.daplipcoding.broadcast.blockWonBroadcast");
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int wonBlock = intent.getIntExtra("wonBlock",255);
            
            //logic to respond to the broadcast 
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

f)  don’t forget to **unregister** the receiver in onPause or similar lifecycle event

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //stop broadcast
    this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

}
```

**Step 3 - In the Manifest – *this step is not necessary for a broadcast that is only dealing with your own app business*** 
a)  register the Activity that will receive the broadcast with the name of the broadcast

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.daplipcoding.broadcast.blockWonBroadcast">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```